# catch all errors and exception related my program

Tags: c++, c, logging, gdb

I am currently working on a c++ daemon program that listen on a port for incoming requests.

I would like to catch all the errors related to the program for that I implemented a logger in my program and catched some eventual ones, but other errors remain uncatchable using those methodes, example the Segfault or if the program was stopped because of memory shortage.
I had the idea of using the 'bmesg' which contains logs of different process and then take what I need from there. the problem with this approach is that the logs from 'bmesg' don't contain human readable information more than that, the logs are not dated, so i used 'gdb' on my program, now i logs are more elaborated and contain better information but i can't catch the message of 'gdb'
my questions are:

1. Is my approach to this problem correct? If yes how can i continue from where i am now
2. Is there another way to listen to errors better than this.
3. I will need somthing similar in a C program do you have a suggestion.

**EDIT**

after some research i think i will use another deamon to check every 5 min or so if my other deamon is running or not in order to re-launch it if its down. with this setteled i now need to record the error. this is where i am stuck

Comment: If you can't log errors from within the program after segfault or stack overflow, you can log *intended* actions before attempting them.

Comment: i already did that. I am using log4cpp, but i would like to have more information than what is the last action that has been executed.in order to debug easly and be able to re-run the program if possible

Comment: Perhaps you need a two-stage process. First to isolate where the error is occurring. When you have found it, record more detailed information, perhaps with home-made tools writing to a file yourself.

Comment: yes this is my goal. after some research i think i will use another deamon to check every 5 min or so if my other deamon is running or not in order to re-launch it if its down. with this setteled i now need to record the error. this is where i am stuck.

Comment: Use  a master process that `fork()`s the actual worker process and then blocks indefinitely `wait()`ing for it.  If the child process crashes, `wait` will return you an error exit code that you can log and eventually restart the child process.

Comment: To add to what @5gon12eder suggested, as the child process runs, it can re-write some diagnostic data to file, shared memory, etc. Then, the parent process can log this when the child crashes.

Comment: i got your point. i will try to implement this solution right now. thanks for the help